# How to connect to a public FTP server using Paramiko in Python?

Tags: python, ftp, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a public FTP server using Paramiko.
Since the FTP server is public it don't have username and password.
So I run following commands:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
trans = paramiko.Transport(("ftp.***.com", 22))
trans.connect()
```

But I am getting error in executing the last command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/userstar713/workspace/work/serverless/python/ftp-s3-sls/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1291, in connect
    self.start_client()
  File "/home/userstar713/workspace/work/serverless/python/ftp-s3-sls/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 660, in start_client
    raise e
  File "/home/userstar713/workspace/work/serverless/python/ftp-s3-sls/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/userstar713/workspace/work/serverless/python/ftp-s3-sls/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2216, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Please give me suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Paramiko is an SFTP library, not FTP library. SFTP servers that do not require any credentials are almost non-existent. And even the error message you are getting suggests that you are not connecting to an SFTP server.

If it is indeed an FTP server, you need to use an FTP library, like [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html).